# All values of input array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
double ini = 1;
    for (int m = 1; m < arraydc.length - 1; m++)
    {
        if (arrtemp[m][0] == arrtemp[m + 1][0])
        {
            arrdec[m][0] = ini;
            arrdec[m][1] = arrtemp[m][1];
        }
        else
        {
            arrdec[m][0] = ini;
            arrdec[m][1] = arrtemp[m][1];
            arrdec[m + 1][0] = ini++;
            arrdec[m + 1][1] = arrtemp[m + 1][1];
        }
        System.out.println(arrdec[m][0] + "\t\t");
    }
```

From the above code I want to assign values to the elements of the array in the following manner:

This is the input array (rows 5, i am not considering the row 1, and hence that's why started the counter from m=1):

```
6.0             
8.0     
23.0    
24.0
```

I want the output like the following (because all the elements of the array are diffrent):

```
1.0     
2.0     
3.0 
4.0
```

Likewise, if the input is the following array:

```
25.0        
25.0        
30.0    
30.0
```

Then The output should be like this (equal value elements will be replaced by the same number)

```
1.0     
1.0     
2.0 
2.0
```

But, the output I m getting is only upto 3 values :

```
1.0
1.0
2.0
```

Help me with the crrection of my code so that I can get the values in output for all elements of the input array.

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger will be a much more efficient and reliable way to find the error than asking people to find it for you.

Comment: are you sure the loop starts from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @richard yes i m sure.. I am not considering the values at index '0' because they all are null and are not required to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your for statement condition
`m < arraydc.length - 1`  ->   `m < arraydc.length`

EDIT: do this:

```
double ini = 1;
for (int m = 1; m < arraydc.length; m++)
{
    arrdec[m][1] = arrtemp[m][1]; 
    if (m != 1 && arrtemp[m][0] == arrtemp[m - 1][0])
    {
        ini++;           
    }
    arrdec[m][0] = ini;
    System.out.println(arrdec[m][0] + "\t\t");
}
```